# How to receive all files within a folder?

Tags: c#, file, sorting, filtering

I would like to find out how to receive and store all file names within a folder into a list.

I've been searching for posts and this is what I have so far:

```
private void btnSort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        //if (Directory.Exists(Path)) 
        foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(FilePath))
        {
            NoOfFiles++;
            FileNames.Add(file);
            //Should implement adding something that converts lower case letters to upper.
            Directory.CreateDirectory(FilePath + "\\" + file[0]);
        }
}
```

It works to a degree, but I would like to create a directory named with the first letter of the file (E.g. `RndFile.txt`), not the file path (E.g. `C:\\something\\something\\RndFile.txt`).

Therefore, I would like to store that information inside a list.

However, I do not how to only receive this information or remove of the unnecessary parts.

Thanks!
Shivam

P.S. For people who are interested, this is for an A-Level Computing Project. I'm creating a simple, badly coded, program to sort files according to their first letter. I'm making it badly to ask my teacher if this would be a good idea for it or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your problem correctly.

The Path namespace contains some useful functions. I think you want

`Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension()` - and that gives you just the filename. Then you can treat it as a string and

`Substring(0,1)` to get the first letter.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DirectoryInfo` instead of `Directory`:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo("c:");
FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
```

Answer (score 0):

FileInfo  object in System.IO gives file name by Name property:

```
     private void btnSort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("path");
            FileInfo[] fi = di.GetFiles();
            foreach (FileInfo item in fi)
            {
                string filename = item.Name;
                string fullname = item.FullName;
            }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static string[] GetFileNames(string path, string filter)
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, filter);
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
        {
            files[i] = Path.GetFileName(files[i]);

        }
        return files;
    }
```

Call this function in page load

```
string[] myFiles = GetFileNames("D:\\folderName", "*.txt");
```

`myFiles` array now contains name of all files stord inside folder .
To sort the filenames , simply sort the array files

```
Array.Sort(myFiles);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your work it is quite right, you just need to add the functionalities provided by the [class Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) to your loop

```
private void btnSort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(FilePath))
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
        string newDir = Path.Combine(FilePath, fileName[0]);
        if(!Directory.Exists(newDir))
             Directory.CreateDirectory(newDir);

        // If you still need to store the filenames in a list you could add
        FileNames.Add(fileName);
        // but no need to keep a counter variable, you could Always get that value
        // using FileNames.Count after the loop ends...

    }
}
```